# How to implement access protected by username in spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a case where certain endpoints on a controller should return 401 if the username that the user authenticated with is the same username as the user being operated on.

I have been thinking of the best way to do this. Currently, I have an authentication facade (https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) where I check in the body of each controller method if the user should have access to operate on the item it is asking to.

IE. A user should only be able to delete their account:

```
User u = service.findOne(id);
if (u != null) {
    // user can only delete their own account
    User authenticated = authenticationFacade.getAuthUser();
    RestPreconditions.checkRequestState(authenticated.getId() == u.getId());
}
```

Another case is where a user needs to operate on something of a different data type that they have access to work on.

IE

```
Post p = service.findOne(id);
if (p != null) {
        // user can only delete their own posts
        User authenticated = authenticationFacade.getAuthUser();
        RestPreconditions.checkRequestState(authenticated.getId() == p.getUser().getId());
}
```

I am here to ask if this is the best way. As demonstrated above, some of the checks require operating through different objects and making database calls to get the data to determine if the user should have access.

I considered a role-based implementation and was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into how I would do that and if it is cleaner than the method above.

The reason I ask is that I also want to allow people with the ROLE_ADMIN role to be able to do all operations but I would need to transform the current checks to or || with the current checks and that seems messy. But simply preauthorizing just role admin would still fail with the facade without the or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check about  [`@PreAuthorize` / `@PostAuthorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize) which allows you to use [`SpEL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) to secure a method call in a declarative way.

One of the very nice thing is that you can even [uses SpEL to refer a spring bean method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans) , which means you can do something like below.

First, defining a bean to encapsulate all the security related checking.Suppose all entities implements some sort of interface (e.g BaseEntity) which can get the owner of that entity :

```
@Service
public class SecurityService{

     public boolean isAllowAccessedByCurrentUser(BaseEntity entity) {
            User authenticated = authenticationFacade.getAuthUser();
            return authenticated.getId() == entity.getOwnerId();
     }
}
```

To use it to apply the security checking :

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    //"returnObject" is the built-in variable referring to the return object 
    @PostAuthorize ("@securityService.isAllowAccessedByCurrentUser(returnObject)")
    public User findOne(Integer id){

    }
}



@Service
public class PostService {

    //"returnObject" is the built-in variable refer to the return object of the method
    @PostAuthorize ("@securityService.isAllowAccessedByCurrentUser(returnObject)")
    public Post findOne(Integer id){

    }
}
```

Comment: This makes life a lot easier when the object being returned contains the ID. However, there are some cases (delete endpoint for example) that  takes an ID for an object to be deleted and returns void). I cant use the method params to find ownership of the object cuz its just an ID, and it returns nothing. There needs to be a call to a service that gets the actual object from the database. Can i use spel for that?